# localStorage is not defined when building. Nextjs and Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, redux

I am building an app in NextJs using the Restcountries API. I am using redux for simulating a cart/fav-list component. But when I run "build" I am having an error saying that "localStorage is not defined"

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "@redux-devtools/extension";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { DefaultState } from "redux/reducers";
import reducer from "../reducers";

function saveToLocalStorage(state: DefaultState) {
  try {
    const localStorageState = JSON.stringify(state);
    localStorage.setItem("statePersist", localStorageState);
  } catch (e) {
    console.warn(e);
  }
}

function loadFromLocalStorage() {
  try {
    const localStorageState = localStorage.getItem("statePersist");
    if (localStorageState === null) return undefined;
    return JSON.parse(localStorageState);
  } catch (e) {
    console.warn(e);
  }
  return undefined;
}

const storeFactory = () => {
  const middlewares = [thunk];
  const reduxStore = createStore(
    reducer,
    loadFromLocalStorage(),
    composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middlewares))
  );
  reduxStore.subscribe(() => saveToLocalStorage(reduxStore.getState()));
  return reduxStore;
};

const midi = storeFactory();

export type Store = ReturnType<typeof storeFactory>;
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof midi.getState>;
export default storeFactory;
```